# How to make payment method visible in admin order creation

Tags: magento-1.9

We need to often create orders in the backend via the admin panel. Currently three payment methods are available, credit/debit card, bank transfer and purchase order. I however need more than that, others are activated in the config>system but are still not visible in admin order creation.

Could any one please advise?

I would be grateful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each payment method model supports a member called `$_canUseInternal`. This decides if the payment method can be used in the backend.
So you need to add this in the payment method model

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
```

But chances are you will need more than that, depending on the payment method. You may need to create a block and/or a template for admin use.
Some of the payment method might not be designed to work on the backend.

**[Edit]**
If you need a method just to appear on the invoice and no actions behind it then you can create your own. Here is a [nice tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module) for creating one.
Just make sure you set to it

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
protected $_canUseCheckout = false;
protected $_canUseForMultishipping = false;
```

so you can use it only for frontend.

Comment: I only need it to be visible on the invoice in a text format, i.e 'cash' it doens tneed to capture any information or do anything else. so I would edit app > code > core >Mage > payment > model > method ?

Comment: @DanielTyas. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In magento every payment method extend `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` and has the below member variables

```
protected $_canUseInternal              = true; //This can use in admin
protected $_canUseCheckout              = true; //This can use in onepage checkout
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = true; //This can use in multishipping
```

By default all are `true`

If you wanna use method for admin only then just use below code

```
protected $_canUseInternal              = true; //This can use in admin
protected $_canUseCheckout              = false; //This can use in onepage checkout
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = false; //This can use in multishipping
```