# Payment methods not appearing for admin orders

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, payment-methods

We recently upgraded our 1.8 installation to 1.9.2.4 and now when we try to add a product to an order via the admin area (Admin > Sales > Orders > Create New Order) none of the set up Payment methods appear.

[image]

As far as I can see all configuration is correct. I've found a similar question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65745/payment-methods-option-page-in-magento-admin-config-payment-methods-not-opening) but there is no answer and the suggestions do not work either.

Comment: You can refer this [answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68510/how-to-make-payment-method-visible-in-admin-order-creation.) I think it will be helpful for you.

Comment: @Manikandan which file do I add that comment to? I've seen it suggested before

Comment: Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract in this model you can find the code.@evilscary

Comment: @Manikandan I found the file and added the code but still no luck. No payment methods appear at all in the admin area, but all the method models are set to $_canUseInternal = true

Comment: add the code which i have refereed from a developer answer@evilscary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise I never accepted an answer for this.

It turned out to be a clash between two modules we had installed that was causing the options in question to be hidden.

After updating the modules the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Each payment method model supports a member called `$_canUseInternal`. This decides if the payment method can be used in the backend.
So you need to add this in the payment method model

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
```

But chances are you will need more than that, depending on the payment method. You may need to create a block and/or a template for admin use.
Some of the payment method might not be designed to work on the backend.

If you need a method just to appear on the invoice and no actions behind it then you can create your own. Here is a <strike>[nice tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module)</strike> for creating one.
Just make sure you set to it

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
protected $_canUseCheckout = false;
protected $_canUseForMultishipping = false;
```

so you can use it only for frontend.

Comment: None of the default payment methods appear in the admin area at all. All I need is for any payment methods to appear!

Comment: http://lucdebrouwer.nl/enabling-magento-payment-methods-for-backend-orders/

Comment: follow the steps in this link.

Comment: I have already run through that guide with no change

Comment: which payment options you are using for your site.

Comment: The default ones plus paypal I think. The site is inherited from another developer.

Answer (score 1):

In magento every payment method extend `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` and has the below member variables

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true; //This can use in admin 
protected $_canUseCheckout = true; //This can use in onepage checkout 
protected $_canUseForMultishipping = true; //This can use in multishipping
```

By default all are true

If you wanna use method for admin only then just use below code

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true; //This can use in admin 
protected $_canUseCheckout = false; //This can use in onepage checkout
protected $_canUseForMultishipping = false; //This can use in multishipping
```

Comment: These are all enabled, no payment methods appear in the admin area at all.

Comment: Is there any third party module installed for payment method? if so means disable it and check