# Magento 1.9 The requested Payment Method is not available

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, payment-methods

We want to disable a specific payment method, because we changed to another payment service provider.

But when we disable the module, we can not open the old orders anymore.
We get the error: The requested Payment Method is not available.

Is there a way to easily solve this, to open these old orders?

Comment: Check this post. This will help you. [Enable payment method only for admin user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68510/how-to-make-payment-method-visible-in-admin-order-creation)

Comment: Check answers & give feedback

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not deal well with this scenario: deleting/disabling a payment method that has been used. Your have two options here:

1. installing the old extension again from a backup or similar
2. adjust the payment method in the database(Not Recommend)

So first approach is clear that we can not disable the extension because it can have multiple dependency so we have to keep the extension we can deal this situation using other option like manipulating our databases and placed orders which is not appropriate approach.

so in my knowledge we should not disable extension like payment method which can have dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by [user55548](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/55548/user55548) here you have an approach for this [How to make payment method visible in admin order creation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68510/how-to-make-payment-method-visible-in-admin-order-creation)

However, you should be aware that using...

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
```

Will show payment method as available when creating new orders through admin (which could be a problem if there are some customer service users working in the project)

You should play then with **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/billing/method/form.phtml** template (or maybe rewrite **Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container::getMethods()** to add your custom logic) to exclude that method when creating admin orders